# how to allow pop ups and redirect settings in programmatically with chrome extension development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Hope you are doing well.
I am going to open multiple tabs in chrome browser with chrome extension, but need to allow to set pop ups and redirect setting in browser settings manually to run correctly as following [Link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

One tab is opening well with `window.open` in javascript.
But multiple tabs in simultenously is not working without setting pop ups and redirect.
Pop-up blocked
Any ideas to set up the setting for this?
Thank you in advance.

```
var links = ["https://www.example1.com", "https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example3.com"]; 
for (var i in links){
    window.open(i, "_newtab");
}
```

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.create

Comment: I've tried, but not working. any other ideas?

Comment: Add `active: false` to parameters if you open it in the action popup.